# Gravity Forms Create Dynamic Input Names & Id's

Tags: forms, wordpress, gravity

I'm going to do my best to describe what I'm attempting to do, and what I've done, but, please let me know if you need more information to provide help.

What I'm trying to do is create an html table that has 5 columns and any number of rows. It's a very basic order form that will list literature that we have for sale. The first 4 columns provide information about the item, and the 5th column is a simply text input "qty" field that allows a user to enter the "qty" of the item they wish to purchase. You can see what this looks like here: http://web.go-spi.com/cgl/literature/.

It's important to note that the table is generated dynamically, via a custom loop that I've created in Wordpress. I did it this way to allow us to dynamically add or remove literature items from the table.

The code:

```
<div class='gf_browser_chrome gform_wrapper' id='gform_wrapper_6' >
<a id='gf_6' name='gf_6' class='gform_anchor' ></a>
<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='gform_ajax_frame_6' id='gform_6'  action='/cgl/literature/#gf_6'>
<div class='gform_body'>
<div id='gform_fields_6' class='gform_fields top_label description_below'>

<?php $literature_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'literature', 'showposts' => '50', 'orderby' => 'meta_value', 'meta_key' => 'ecpt_brochurerow', 'order' => 'ASC'));
if( $literature_query->have_posts() ):?>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="data">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Brochure Type</th>
            <th><label class='gfield_label' for='input_6_1'>Description</label></th>
            <th>Cost</th>
            <th>Qty/Pack</th>
            <th><label class='gfield_label' for='input_6_2'>Qty</label></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php  while( $literature_query->have_posts() ): $literature_query->the_post();?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ecpt_brochuregroup', true); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ecpt_brochuredescription', true); ?><input type='hidden' class='gform_hidden' name='input_1' id='input_6_1' value="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ecpt_brochuredescription', true); ?>"/></td>
    <td><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ecpt_brochurecost', true); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ecpt_brochureqtyperpack', true); ?></td>
    <td><input name='input_2' id='input_6_2' type='text' value='' class='medium'/></td>
    </tr>
<?php endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();   
?>
</tbody>
</table>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="alert alert-block">
<p>Sorry, there is currently no literature available. Please check back later.</p>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
</div>
<div class='gform_footer top_label'> 
<input type='submit' id='gform_submit_button_6' class='button gform_button' value='Submit' tabindex='1' /><input type='hidden' name='gform_ajax' value='form_id=6&amp;title=&amp;description=' />
<input type='hidden' class='gform_hidden' name='is_submit_6' value='1' />
<input type='hidden' class='gform_hidden' name='gform_submit' value='6' />
<input type='hidden' class='gform_hidden' name='gform_unique_id' value='5077469db6b44' />
<input type='hidden' class='gform_hidden' name='state_6' value='YToyOntpOjA7czo2OiJhOjA6e30iO2k6MTtzOjMyOiJjMDlmZjFlZmU1MjMzN2M3M2FkODliMmVjY2Y5YzIxMyI7fQ==' />
<input type='hidden' class='gform_hidden' name='gform_target_page_number_6' id='gform_target_page_number_6' value='0' />
<input type='hidden' class='gform_hidden' name='gform_source_page_number_6' id='gform_source_page_number_6' value='1' />
<input type='hidden' name='gform_field_values' value='' />          
</div>

</form>
</div>

<iframe style='display:none;width:0px; height:0px;' src='about:blank' name='gform_ajax_frame_6' id='gform_ajax_frame_6'></iframe>
<script type='text/javascript'>function gformInitSpinner_6(){jQuery('#gform_6').submit(function(){if(jQuery('#gform_ajax_spinner_6').length == 0){jQuery('#gform_submit_button_6').attr('disabled', true).after('<' + 'img id="gform_ajax_spinner_6"  class="gform_ajax_spinner" src="/cgl/wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/images/spinner.gif" alt="" />');jQuery('#gform_wrapper_6 .gform_previous_button').attr('disabled', true); jQuery('#gform_wrapper_6 .gform_next_button, #gform_wrapper_6 .gform_image_button').attr('disabled', true).after('<' + 'img id="gform_ajax_spinner_6"  class="gform_ajax_spinner" src="/cgl/wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/images/spinner.gif" alt="" />');}} );}jQuery(document).ready(function($){gformInitSpinner_6();jQuery('#gform_ajax_frame_6').load( function(){var contents = jQuery(this).contents().find('*').html();var is_postback = contents.indexOf('GF_AJAX_POSTBACK') >= 0;if(!is_postback){return;}var form_content = jQuery(this).contents().find('#gform_wrapper_6');var is_redirect = contents.indexOf('gformRedirect(){') >= 0;jQuery('#gform_submit_button_6').removeAttr('disabled');var is_form = !(form_content.length <= 0 || is_redirect);if(is_form){jQuery('#gform_wrapper_6').html(form_content.html());jQuery(document).scrollTop(jQuery('#gform_wrapper_6').offset().top);if(window['gformInitDatepicker']) {gformInitDatepicker();}if(window['gformInitPriceFields']) {gformInitPriceFields();}var current_page = jQuery('#gform_source_page_number_6').val();gformInitSpinner_6();jQuery(document).trigger('gform_page_loaded', [6, current_page]);}else if(!is_redirect){var confirmation_content = jQuery(this).contents().find('#gforms_confirmation_message').html();if(!confirmation_content){confirmation_content = contents;}setTimeout(function(){jQuery('#gform_wrapper_6').replaceWith('<' + 'div id=\'gforms_confirmation_message\' class=\'gform_confirmation_message_6\'' + '>' + confirmation_content + '<' + '/div' + '>');jQuery(document).scrollTop(jQuery('#gforms_confirmation_message').offset().top);jQuery(document).trigger('gform_confirmation_loaded', [6]);}, 50);}else{jQuery('#gform_6').append(contents);if(window['gformRedirect']) {gformRedirect();}}jQuery(document).trigger('gform_post_render', [6, current_page]);} );} );</script><script type='text/javascript'> jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery(document).trigger('gform_post_render', [6, 1]) } ); </script>
```

The problem:

1) I'm not sure how to dynamically set the input name and id so that they are sequential as you go down the form. Currently, as the code is set up, I'll only receive the submitted value of the first input no matter how many inputs are filled in.

I appreciate any help you can provide. Thanks!

Comment: Could you do it after the fact with javascript, cycling through each entry?